# Objeto nulo com jquery ajax MVC3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Eu sei que devo estar esquecendo alguma coisa.

Estou fazendo uma requisição ajax jquery para enviar uma mensagem via formulário de contato, porém o objeto está chegando nulo no `controller`.

Tentei fazendo com o `JSON.stringfy` e sem ele, com ele chega o objeto com todas as propriedades nulas, sem ele o objeto em si chega nulo

Fiz a mesma requisição em outro formulário e funcionou. Esse tem mais campos e não está funcionando, segue meu código:

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="return EnviarMensagem()">
    <div class="w-form form-wrapper">
        <div class="w-clearfix" id="email-form" name="email-form" data-name="Email Form">
            <div class="w-row">
                <div class="w-col w-col-4">
                    <address class="form-content-box">
                        <p class="form-content-box-title">
                            @ViewBag.Contato_Box_Titulo
                        </p>
                        <p class="contact-form-info">
                            @ViewBag.Contato_Box_Texto
                            <br><br>
                            <a class="contact-form-info-phone" href="tel:3274-1710">
                                @ViewBag.Contato_Box_Rodape
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </address>
                </div>
                <div class="w-col w-col-4">
                    <input type="text" id="Nome" placeholder="Seu Nome (obrigatório)" class="w-input form-text-field" data-name="Nome" required />
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nome, new { @class = "w-input form-text-field", placeholder = "Seu Nome (obrigatório)", required = "required" })*@
                    <input type="text" id="Email" placeholder="Seu E-mail (obrigatório)" required data-name="EMail" class="w-input form-text-field" />
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "w-input form-text-field", placeholder = "Seu E-mail (obrigatório)", required = "required" })*@
                    <input type="text" id="Telefone" placeholder="Telefone)" required data-name="Telefone" class="w-input form-text-field" />
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telefone, new { @class = "w-input form-text-field", placeholder = "Seu Telefone" })*@
                </div>
                <div class="w-col w-col-4">
                    <textarea class="w-input form-text-area" cols="20" id="Mensagem" name="Mensagem" placeholder="Deixe a sua mensagem" rows="2"></textarea>
                    @*@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Mensagem, new { @class = "w-input form-text-area", placeholder = "Deixe a sua mensagem" })*@
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="w-button form-button-submit" data-wait="Aguarde..." wait="Aguarde..." />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="w-form-done form-message-success" style="display: none;" id="BoxMensagem">
            <p class="form-message-text" id="mensagemSucesso">Obrigado pelo interesse! Em breve você receberá novidades sobre casos de sucesso em seu e-mail.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
   function EnviarMensagem() {
        var data = ObterData();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Mensagem/EnviarMensagem",
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#BoxMensagem').css('display', 'block').css('background-color', '#00626b');
                $('#mensagemSucesso').html('Aguarde, estamos registrando seu contato.');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#mensagemSucesso').html('Obrigado pelo interesse! Em breve você receberá as melhores oportunidades em seu e-mail.');
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

    function ObterData() {
        var data = '{ ';

        data += '"Nome": "' + $('#Nome').val() + '", ';
        data += '"Email": "' + $('#Email').val() + '", ';
        data += '"Telefone": "' + $('#Telefone').val() + '", ';
        data += '"Mensagem": "' + $('#Mensagem').val() + '", ';
        data += '"TipoMensagem": 2 }';

        return data;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EnviarMensagem(MensagemDto mensagem)
{
    var mensagemHtml = GerarMensagemHtml(mensagem);
    var tipoMensagem = (TipoMensagem)mensagem.TipoMensagem;

    EnviarEmail(mensagemHtml, tipoMensagem);
    SalvarContato(mensagem);

    return Json(new { Sucesso = true });
}
```

**Objeto - MensagemDto**

```
public class MensagemDto
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }

    public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
    public string TipoImovel { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Tamanho { get; set; }
    public string CodigoCenture { get; set; }
    public string Preco { get; set; }

    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    public int TipoMensagem { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Olá, não testei aqui, e nem nunca fiz a criação de um objeto da forma que está fazendo na função _ObterData_, mas não seria o fato de estar criando o objeto todo dentro de uma _string_?

Comment: Oi @TácioBrito acredito que se fosse isso não funcionaria no outro formulário também. Esse tipo de objeto eu crio pra todas as requisições que fiz até agora. No Network do devtools do navegador, ele mostra o objeto convertido para JSON normalmente. Quando não se faz assim, se usa o JSON.stringfy

Comment: Entendi, eu nunca fiz dessa forma. Enfim, pesquiser sobre o _Bind_ e tente usar no seu controller: **public ActionResult EnviarMensagem(Bind MensagemDto mensagem)**

Comment: @TácioBrito Assim dá erro de compilação. Não reconhece Bind. Alguma biblioteca que eu deva utilizar?

Comment: como está o mensagemdto?

Comment: Eu utilizo ele no .Net MVC, nesse link tem uma melhor explicação: [link](https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2012/05/06/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-parte-1-defaultmodelbinder/)

Comment: @LucasMiranda atualizei a pergunta com o Dto.

Comment: tenta mudar seu data no ajax para Json.stringfy({ mensagemDto: data})

Comment: @TácioBrito seu link me ajudou a encontrar a resposta, vou colocar aqui embaixo pra não ficar sem resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema era realmente o bind do objeto. Como o meu dto tem uma propriedade chamada Mensagem, o mesmo não conseguia fazer pois tudo praticamente chama Mensagem (Controller, Dto).

Troquei meu Dto e agora ele ficou assim:

```
    public class MensagemDto
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        public string MensagemContato { get; set; }

        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        public string TipoImovel { get; set; }
        public string Cidade { get; set; }
        public string Tamanho { get; set; }
        public string CodigoCenture { get; set; }
        public string Preco { get; set; }

        public string Endereco { get; set; }

        public int TipoMensagem { get; set; }
    }
```

Só pude perceber após ler sobre os binds no link deixado pelo Tácio Brito, segue:

[ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2012/05/06/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-parte-1-defaultmodelbinder/)